# What is the '@=' symbol for in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, matrix-multiplication, python-3.5

I know `@` is for decorators, but what is `@=` for in Python? Is it just reservation for some future idea?

This is just one of my many questions while reading `tokenizer.py`.

Comment: See cset [c553d8f72d65](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/c553d8f72d65) ([GitHub mirror...easier to read](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/c8555769ea6ca6ce7718172d8e9830593ac2ae94)) in the CPython repo.

Comment: SymbolHound is a search-engine which can search on punctuation symbols. However [searching on @= python](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%40%3D+python) doesn't currently return relevant results, because Python 3.5 documentation contains '@' but not an example of '@=' anywhere. I sent SH a message to help improve that. Python doc could improve too.

Comment: Combined with the `:=` [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) of Python 3.8, you get what's known as the `@:=` thorny rose operator. (Or in Japan it's known as the Elvis-walrus operator.)

Answer (score 267, accepted):

From [the](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements):

> The `@` (at) operator is intended to be used for matrix multiplication. No builtin Python types implement this operator.

The `@` operator was introduced in Python 3.5. `@=` is matrix multiplication followed by assignment, as you would expect. They map to `__matmul__`, `__rmatmul__` or `__imatmul__` similar to how `+` and `+=` map to `__add__`, `__radd__` or `__iadd__`.

The operator and the rationale behind it are discussed in detail in [PEP 465](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

Comment: That explains why it's in the latest version of tokenizer.py but not the 3.4 docs.

Comment: This is covered in 3.5's docs - https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements and https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Comment: Does this have conflict with Python decorators? This is not implemented in Python 2.n, right?

Comment: This does not conflict decorators, because decorators may never be preceded by an expression, and binary operators must always be preceded by an expression.

Answer (score 123):

`@=` and `@` are new operators introduced in Python **3.5** performing **matrix multiplication**. They are meant to clarify the confusion which existed so far with the operator `*` which was used either for element-wise multiplication or matrix multiplication depending on the convention employed in that particular library/code. As a result, in the future, the operator `*` is meant to be used for element-wise multiplication only.

As explained in [PEP0465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/), two operators were introduced:

- A new binary operator `A @ B`, used similarly as `A * B`
- An in-place version `A @= B`, used similarly as `A *= B`

#### Matrix Multiplication vs Element-wise Multiplication

To quickly highlight the difference, for two matrices:

```
A = [[1, 2],    B = [[11, 12],
     [3, 4]]         [13, 14]]
```

- Element-wise multiplication will yield:

  ```
  A * B = [[1 * 11,   2 * 12], 
           [3 * 13,   4 * 14]]
  ```
- Matrix multiplication will yield:

  ```
  A @ B  =  [[1 * 11 + 2 * 13,   1 * 12 + 2 * 14],
             [3 * 11 + 4 * 13,   3 * 12 + 4 * 14]]
  ```

#### Usage in Numpy

So far, Numpy used the following convention:

- the `*` operator (and [arithmetic operators](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-and-comparison-operations) in general) were defined as element-wise operations on [ndarrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) and as matrix-multiplication on [numpy.matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) type.
- [method/function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) `dot` was used for matrix multiplication of ndarrays

Introduction of the `@` operator makes the code involving matrix multiplications much easier to read. PEP0465 gives us an example:

```
# Current implementation of matrix multiplications using dot function
S = np.dot((np.dot(H, beta) - r).T,
            np.dot(inv(np.dot(np.dot(H, V), H.T)), np.dot(H, beta) - r))

# Current implementation of matrix multiplications using dot method
S = (H.dot(beta) - r).T.dot(inv(H.dot(V).dot(H.T))).dot(H.dot(beta) - r)

# Using the @ operator instead
S = (H @ beta - r).T @ inv(H @ V @ H.T) @ (H @ beta - r)
```

Clearly, the last implementation is much easier to read and interpret as an equation.

Comment: Just for clarification: from your first example, we could think that `@` has been implemented for `list`, which is not the case.

Comment: `@` is associated with `np.matmul`, not `np.dot`. The two are similar but not the same.

Comment: @A-B-B, perhaps you could provide an example clarifying the nuance and ensuring the answer is then complete?

Answer (score 10):

@ is the new operator for Matrix Multiplication added in Python3.5

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465

Example

```
C = A @ B
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy 1.25 will support using `@=` as in place matrix multiplication:

[image]