# How to only iterate certain axis matrix using numpy iteration?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iteration

I want to iterate certain axis inside of matrix using numpy function (specific vector).

Suppose that, We have matrix A that is A.shape(2,3,4)

[[[1,2,3,4],[5,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4]],[[5,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4],[5,7,8,9]]]

For instance, If I want to iterate only axis =2
Iteration = 6

```
[1,2,3,4]
[5,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4]
[5,7,8,9]
[1,2,3,4]
[5,7,8,9]
```

What is the fastest way to do that?

I try to use `numpy.nditer` but I totally stuck.
I think it is sure that use the “external_loop” parameter but still don't know what to do.

```
A_list= np.random.randn(400,400,3)

start_time = time.time()
sum = 0

for i in range(0,400):
    for j in range(0, 400):
        sum += A_list[i][j]

print sum
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

sum = 0
start_time = time.time()

for x in A_list.reshape(-1,A_list.shape[-1]):
    sum += x


print sum
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

sum = 0
start_time = time.time()

for x in np.vstack(A_list):
    sum += x


print sum
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

result :

```
[-196.06613179  643.99881703  264.0386004 ]
--- 0.186000108719 seconds ---
[-196.06613179  643.99881703  264.0386004 ]
--- 0.134000062943 seconds ---
[-196.06613179  643.99881703  264.0386004 ]
--- 0.128999948502 seconds ---
```

Comment: `A.reshape(-1,A.shape[-1])`? `np.vstack(A)` and `np.concatenate(A)` works too.

Comment: These methods takes more time than just use nested for loop.

Comment: What are the dataset sizes? Share your loopy code?

Comment: I hope It would be great about (1500,1500,3)

Comment: I add some code what I tried. It makes little update for reduction of time. Thank

Comment: You should use `sum` ufunc along first two axes : `A_list.sum(axis=(0,1))`

Comment: Thank you for advice but what I really want to do is not summation. I consider axis =2 is the A vector of Ax = b. And want to do extract each A to solve the linear equation.

Comment: If you are talking about [`your previous question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41948035/numpy-solving-3d-linear-equation-without-loop), maybe leave a comment to the posted solution there if it worked?

Comment: How can I handle to the problem of 'Error : too many values to unpack?'

Comment: How/where are you getting that error?

Comment: I tried use vstack for (960,900,3) array it says it is too many values to unpack. like " for i in np.vstack(array(960,900,3)) "

Comment: I can't reproduce. I thought the previous question's solution solved this question, didn't it?

Comment: `nditer` is not a general purpose iterator - at least not a the Python level.  Use it only if you are developing Cython code.