# Scalable solution for dot product of two vectors

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

The dot product of two vectors can be computed via [numpy.dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). Now I want to compute the dot product of an array of vectors:

```
>>> numpy.arange(15).reshape((5, 3))
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])
```

The vectors are row vectors and the output should be a 1d-array containing the results from the dot products:

```
array([  5,  50, 149, 302, 509])
```

For the cross product ([numpy.cross](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html)) this can be easily achieved specifying the `axis` keyword. However `numpy.dot` doesn't have such an option and passing it two 2d-arrays will result in the ordinary matrix product. I also had a look at [numpy.tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) but this doesn't seem to do the job either (being an extended matrix product).

I know that I can compute the dot product per element for 2d-arrays via

```
>>> numpy.einsum('ij, ji -> i', array2d, array2d.T)
```

However this solution doesn't work for 1d-arrays (i.e. just a single element). I would like to obtain a solution that works for both 1d-arrays (returning a scalar) and arrays of 1d-arrays (aka 2d-arrays) (returning a 1d-array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) with `ellipsis(...)` to account for arrays with variable number of dimensions, like so -

```
np.einsum('...i,...i ->...', a, a)
```

Stating the docs on it -

> To enable and control broadcasting, use an ellipsis. Default
>   NumPy-style broadcasting is done by adding an ellipsis to the left of
>   each term, like np.einsum('...ii->...i', a). To take the trace along
>   the first and last axes, you can do np.einsum('i...i', a), or to do a
>   matrix-matrix product with the left-most indices instead of rightmost,
>   you can do np.einsum('ij...,jk...->ik...', a, b).

Sample runs on `2D` and `1D` arrays -

```
In [88]: a
Out[88]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14]])

In [89]: np.einsum('...i,...i ->...', a, a) # On 2D array
Out[89]: array([  5,  50, 149, 302, 509])

In [90]: b = a[:,0]

In [91]: b
Out[91]: array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12])

In [92]: np.einsum('...i,...i ->...', b,b) # On 1D array
Out[92]: 270
```

Runtime test -

Since, we need to keep one axis aligned, at least with `2D` arrays, one of `np.einsum` or [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) or the latest [`@ operator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python) would be efficient.

```
In [95]: a = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

# @unutbu's soln
In [96]: %timeit (a*a).sum(axis=-1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.63 ms per loop

In [97]: %timeit np.einsum('...i,...i ->...', a, a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 944 µs per loop

In [98]: a = np.random.rand(1000)

# @unutbu's soln
In [99]: %timeit (a*a).sum(axis=-1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.11 µs per loop

In [100]: %timeit np.einsum('...i,...i ->...', a, a)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.59 µs per loop
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! I also found that one can use `numpy.linalg.norm(array, axis=-1)**2` however performance is similar to `(a*a).sum(axis=-1)` (i.e. poor compared to `einsum`) which I found quite surprising because I don't see where the call to `einsum` is different from the `linalg.norm` function (apart from squaring but I verified this contribution to be negligible). Do you have an idea why the two functions have such a different performance? (Unless `linalg.norm` evaluates to `sqrt((a*a).sum(axis=-1))`, but then what is `einsum` doing differently?)

Comment: @a_guest Well I have not dug deep into `einsum's` implementation, but based on its performance, I think its a C compiled code. Now, with `numpy.linalg.norm` again based on its performance, I think that elementwise multiplication and then the summing being two stages of such compiled codes and on top of it with `numpy.linalg.norm`, we need the sqrt and then you need to do squaring to get back the desired output is just too much of work, when you compare that with a single piece of compiled code using `einsum`. Disclaimer again: Not an expert on the compilation specifics related to these.