# Row Sum of a dot product for huge matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I have 2 matrix 100kx200 and 200x100k
if they were small matrix I would just use numpy dot product

```
sum(a.dot(b), axis = 0)
```

however the matrix is too big, and also I can't use loops is there a smart way for doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A possible optimization is

```
>>> numpy.sum(a @ b, axis=0)
array([  1.83633615,  18.71643672,  15.26981078, -46.33670382,  13.30276476])
>>> numpy.sum(a, axis=0) @ b
array([  1.83633615,  18.71643672,  15.26981078, -46.33670382,  13.30276476])
```

Computing `a @ b` requires 10k×200×10k operations, while summing the rows first will reduce the multiplication to 1×200×10k operations, giving a 10k× improvement.

This is mainly due to recognizing

```
   numpy.sum(x, axis=0) == [1, 1, ..., 1] @ x
=> numpy.sum(a @ b, axis=0) == [1, 1, ..., 1] @ (a @ b)
                            == ([1, 1, ..., 1] @ a) @ b
                            == numpy.sum(a, axis=0) @ b
```

Similar for the other axis.

```
>>> numpy.sum(a @ b, axis=1)
array([  2.8794171 ,   9.12128399,  14.52009991,  -8.70177811, -15.0303783 ])
>>> a @ numpy.sum(b, axis=1)
array([  2.8794171 ,   9.12128399,  14.52009991,  -8.70177811, -15.0303783 ])
```

(Note: [`x @ y`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python) is equivalent to `x.dot(y)` for [2D matrixes and 1D vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication) on Python 3.5+ with [numpy 1.10.0+](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/release/1.10.0-notes.rst#support-for-the--operator-in-python-35))

---

```
$ INITIALIZATION='import numpy;numpy.random.seed(0);a=numpy.random.randn(1000,200);b=numpy.random.rand(200,1000)'

$ python3 -m timeit -s "$INITIALIZATION" 'numpy.einsum("ij,jk->k", a, b)'
10 loops, best of 3: 87.2 msec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s "$INITIALIZATION" 'numpy.sum(a@b, axis=0)'
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 msec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s "$INITIALIZATION" 'numpy.sum(a, axis=0)@b'
1000 loops, best of 3: 300 usec per loop
```

---

**Illustration:**

```
In [235]: a = np.random.rand(3,3)
array([[ 0.465,  0.758,  0.641],
       [ 0.897,  0.673,  0.742],
       [ 0.763,  0.274,  0.485]])

In [237]: b = np.random.rand(3,2)
array([[ 0.303,  0.378],
       [ 0.039,  0.095],
       [ 0.192,  0.668]])
```

Now, if we simply do `a @ b`, we would need *18 multiply and 6 addition ops*. On the other hand, if we do `np.sum(a, axis=0) @ b` we would only need *6 multiply and 2 addition ops*. An improvement of 3x because we had 3 rows in `a`. As for OP's case, this should give 10k times improvement over simple `a @ b` computation since he has 10k rows in `a`.

Comment: Thank you so much it takes about 0.026 seconds to run

Comment: Just a minor comment regarding your note: the `@` operator is not completely a python 3 feature as it was only introduced in [3.5 release](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465).

Comment: @mgc Thanks. Updated.

Comment: Also, one more thing to note: Your 2nd approach is only possible if we (finally) want to do `sum` along `axis=0`

Answer (score 5):

There are two `sum-reductions` happening - One from the marix-multilication with `np.dot`, and then with the explicit `sum`.

We could use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to do both of those in one go, like so -

```
np.einsum('ij,jk->k',a,b)
```

Sample run -

```
In [27]: a = np.random.rand(3,4)

In [28]: b = np.random.rand(4,3)

In [29]: np.sum(a.dot(b), axis = 0)
Out[29]: array([ 2.70084316,  3.07448582,  3.28690401])

In [30]: np.einsum('ij,jk->k',a,b)
Out[30]: array([ 2.70084316,  3.07448582,  3.28690401])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [45]: a = np.random.rand(1000,200)

In [46]: b = np.random.rand(200,1000)

In [47]: %timeit np.sum(a.dot(b), axis = 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.5 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit np.einsum('ij,jk->k',a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 71.8 ms per loop
```

Sadly, doesn't look like we are doing any better with `np.einsum`.

---

For changing to `np.sum(a.dot(b), axis = 1)`, just swap the output string notation there - `np.einsum('ij,jk->i',a,b)`, like so -

```
In [42]: np.sum(a.dot(b), axis = 1)
Out[42]: array([ 3.97805141,  3.2249661 ,  1.85921549])

In [43]: np.einsum('ij,jk->i',a,b)
Out[43]: array([ 3.97805141,  3.2249661 ,  1.85921549])
```

Comment: Thank you if I wanted to make it for axis=1 what would I change?

Comment: I tried it it has been running for over 5 mins now I guess its slow when it comes to big matrix

Comment: @AyaAbdelsalam Yup! That's what I found out.

Comment: `ij,jk->k` proves the winning solution.  We can sum on `i` first, then do the `j` dot.  I wonder how `np.einsum('j,jk->k', np.einsum('ij->j', a), b)` would do.

Comment: @hpaulj I think `np.einsum('j,jk->k',` part is better off as a matrix multiplication with `dot` as done in the other solution.

Comment: Yes, the `dot` helps a bit.  Seems the big time savings is the `ij->j` step; `einsum` is faster than `np.sum`.  However the OP's arrays are 100x bigger, and `einsum` often falls behind when arrays get really big.

Answer (score 2):

Some quick time tests using the idea I added to Divakar's answer:

```
In [162]: a = np.random.rand(1000,200)
In [163]: b = np.random.rand(200,1000)

In [174]: timeit c1=np.sum(a.dot(b), axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 27.7 ms per loop

In [175]: timeit c2=np.sum(a,axis=0).dot(b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 432 µs per loop

In [176]: timeit c3=np.einsum('ij,jk->k',a,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop

In [177]: timeit c4=np.einsum('j,jk->k', np.einsum('ij->j', a), b)
1000 loops, best of 3: 353 µs per loop

In [178]: timeit np.einsum('ij->j', a) @b
1000 loops, best of 3: 304 µs per loop
```

`einsum` is actually faster than `np.sum`!

```
In [180]: timeit np.einsum('ij->j', a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 173 µs per loop
In [181]: timeit np.sum(a,0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 312 µs per loop
```

For larger arrays the `einsum` advantage decreases

```
In [183]: a = np.random.rand(100000,200)
In [184]: b = np.random.rand(200,100000)
In [185]: timeit np.einsum('ij->j', a) @b
10 loops, best of 3: 51.5 ms per loop
In [186]: timeit c2=np.sum(a,axis=0).dot(b)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: For your first set, I am getting with `np.einsum('ij->j', a)` : `96.8 µs` and with `np.sum(a,0)` : `74.8 µs`. I am on `NumPy 1.12.0`. I think I remember seeing `einsum` being faster than `sum` but on previous versions of NumPy, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Same numpy version here.