# What does @= mean in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, delimiter

I have just read the documentation on delimiters and wonder what does this  delimiter **@=** do?
See the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#delimiters

Comment: In the future, if you want to know what an operator _means_, instead of how it's handled as a token, look in the [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) (or Statements) part of the reference docs instead of the Lexical Analysis section. (The reference docs can be a little confusing the first time you look at them—once you get the hang of it, they're much more readable than most languages' docs, but you do have to get a feel for the organization first. Especially since the search isn't great.)

Comment: Or just Google for "site:stackoverflow.com python @=" or "site:docs.python.org @="...

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, it makes sense, but the best explanation I have received finally here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python