# PyTorch mapping operators to functions

Tags: pytorch, operator-overloading

What are all the PyTorch operators, and what are their function equivalents?

Eg, is `a @ b` equivalent to `a.mm(b)` or `a.matmul(b)`?

I'm after a canonical listing of operator -> function mappings.

I'd be happy to be given a PyTorch documentation link as an answer - my googlefu couldn't track it down.

Comment: Even though it is not that clear as a Doc Link, here are the actual definitions of the operators i.e. `+` and `__add__`:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fa8044d92f8a77b8008ca5e295a341abb9d26f13/torch/tensor.py#L292(This is not the current version, I haven't found such a clear definition in the current version, but I guess there hasn't changed too much)
So you can check what is called then. `@` is defined by `__matmul__`. For the rest you check on [this python docs site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html)  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @blue-phoenox Given those two links, how do I deduce that `@` -> `matmul`?

Comment: Check this and check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python
And check for the `__matmul__` function in the given (first) link.

Answer (score 14):

The Python documentation table [Mapping Operators to Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) provides canonical mappings from:

operator -> `__function__()`

Eg:

> ```
> Matrix Multiplication        a @ b        matmul(a, b)
> ```

Elsewhere on the page, you will see the `__matmul__` name as an alternate to `matmul`.

The definitions of the PyTorch `__functions__` are found either in:

- The [`torch.Tensor` module documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/tensor.html)
- [`python_variable_methods.cpp`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e35418b3bec2f64814919f60aae9d98650771a3a/tools/autograd/templates/python_variable_methods.cpp#L625)

You can look up the documentation for the named functions at:

```
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?#torch.<FUNCTION-NAME>
```

Comment: what is `x.mm(y)` then?

Comment: @CharlieParker [`.mm()` is a non-broadcasting .matmul()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.mm.html?highlight=mm#torch.mm)

Answer (score 6):

This defines tensor operations for 0.3.1 (it does also contain the definitions of the other operators):
https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/_modules/torch/tensor.html

The code for the current stable has been rearranged (I guess they do more in C now), but since the behaviour of matrix multiplication hasn't changed,  I think it is save to  assume that this is still valid.

See for the definition of `__matmul__`:

```py
def __matmul__(self, other):
    if not torch.is_tensor(other):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.matmul(other)
```

and

```py
def matmul(self, other):
    r"""Matrix product of two tensors.

    See :func:`torch.matmul`."""
    return torch.matmul(self, other)
```

The operator `@` was introduced with [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) and is mapped to `__matmul__`.

See also here for this:
[What is the '@=' symbol for in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python)

Comment: Cheers! FYI, I think I found the [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53373484/5353461)