# What do * and mean stand for in this PyTorch expression?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

I do not understand how to evaluate this expression:

```
x.view(*(x.shape[:-2]),-1).mean(-1)`,
```

if `x.shape == (N, C, H, W)`.

What does the asterisk `*` stand for? And what is `mean(-1)` ?

Comment: this pytorch expression? The title for this needs to improve

Comment: for others that were lost due to the bad naming of this question here is the link for other contexts of * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370003/pytorch-mapping-operators-to-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is `*`?

For [`.view()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) pytorch expects the new shape to be provided by *individual* int arguments (represented in the doc as `*shape`). The asterisk (`*`) can be used in python to unpack a list into its individual elements, thus passing to `view` the correct form of input arguments it expects.
So, in your case, `x.shape` is `(N, C, H, W)`, if you were to pass `x.shape[:-2]` *without* the asterisk, you would get `x.view((N, C), -1)` - which is **not** what `view()` expects. Unpacking `(N, C)` using the asterisk results with `view` receiving `view(N, C, -1)` arguments as it expects. The resulting shape is `(N, C, H*W)` (a 3D tensor instead of 4).

> What is `mean(-1)`?

Simply look at the documentation of [`.mean()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.mean): the first argument is a `dim` argument. That is `x.mean(-1)` applies `mean` along the last dimension. In your case, since `keepdim=False` by default, your output will be a `(N, C)` sized tensor where each element correspond to the mean value along both spatial dimensions.
This is equivalent to

```
x.mean(-1).mean(-1)
```

Comment: what does it mena here though `x = y * z` if y and z are tensors? (e.g. what sizes do they need to be)

Comment: @CharlieParker this is a simple element-wise multiplication
 they should have the same size, or a broadcastable one

Comment: yea, I think I was looking for `@` (to make matters worse there seems to be a difference between `.mm` vs `.matmul`...)