# Difference of torch.matmul and python built-in @ operator to do matrix multiplication

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

Can I always replace torch.matmul with python's built-in @ operator to do the matrix multiplication? Please assume that I know the difference between torch.matmul, torch.mm and many others. I just want to make sure how many of them can be safely replaced by @ operator without sacrificing speed or some native support from torch.

If it does no harm, I would like to extensively use them in the future.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can always use `@` in place of `.matmul`. You can also do the same in `numpy`. Also see [PyTorch mapping operators to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370003/pytorch-mapping-operators-to-functions)