# @ (at) like operator in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, operators

I am reading [Python 3.6 Operators](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) and found **@** as one of them.
Anyone can explain why @ is an operator? How operate it? This refers to *decorators*?

I know that decorators use @, thus, Decorators is considered an Operator?

Thanks

Comment: This explains my question, @ is a matrix multiplication .https://stackoverflow.com/a/30629255/6760642

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because the `@`symbol is **not** only used for decorators as per [PEP 465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)