# Matrix multiplication in Python without Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

According to [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) python has an operator `@` that represents `matmul` to multiply matrices. I have used this operator with numpy, however, I think that Python should not be module-specific so there must be some way to make this work without numpy. I tried defining two 2D python lists

```py
b = [list(range(10))]*3
a = [list(range(3))]*10
```

however when I tried doing `a@b` I got `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'list' and 'list'`. How do I use the `@` operator without Numpy?

Comment: Did you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27385659/2320035) (`No builtin Python types implement this operator.`)?

Comment: You say you want to do matrix multiplication but you don't have any matrices in your example. In fact Python doesn't have any built-in `matrix` type, so matrix multiplication doesn't make much sense here. But of course you're free to implement your own :-) By the way `Ellipsis` is also mostly used by Numpy (though it found its application within Python, in the `typing` module for example).

Comment: The answer essentially being: you can't unless you specifically define custom classes that can make use of it.

Comment: Write a function maybe ... ?