# How can I solve this SyntaxError: invalid syntax?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and got this code from GitHub but got an error 
with the `@` symbol:

```py
x=x @ self.wHidden
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I couldn't find the solution by searching for this error.

```py
    if self.hidden:
          x=x @ self.wHidden
          x.add_(self.wHiddenBias)
          x=x.clamp(min=0)
          x=self.dropout(x)
        x=x @ self.wNeu
        x.add_(self.wNeuBias)
```

Comment: what is the git url that you got this code snippet from? the `@` symbol is used to define properties or decorators in python

Comment: what are you trying to do with this: `x=x @ self.wHidden` that is simply not valid python syntax, and I can't intuit what you were intending to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of Python.  The 'matmul' operator `@` was introduced in Python 3.5, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.matmul).

See the example code:

```
class Asdf:

    def __init__ (self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __matmul__ (self, y):
        return self.x * y

a = Asdf (5)

print (a @ 3)
```

It runs fine on Python3:

```
$ python3 ./asdf.py 
15
```

But it fails on Python2, with the same error as you listed above:

```
$ python2 ./asdf.py 
  File "./asdf.py", line 16
    print (a @ 3)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python) answer for details on the matmul operator.