# Principal Component Analysis with python

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I am trying to get the covariance matrix of a centered dataset using the formula

```
Sigma = (A.T @ A)/(n-1)
```

but I keep getting a syntax error for the @ symbol. Is there another way to multiply the two?

Comment: I think the `@` was introduced with v3.5... do you have that?

Comment: no, I am using version 2.7

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/30629255/2836621

Comment: Thank you. I have managed to solve the issue.

Comment: Well done. Good luck with your project!