# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when training a neural network model

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, training-data

I am trying to train a model (https://github.com/bmild/nerf), and I am getting the error below when I run [this](https://github.com/bmild/nerf/blob/master/load_llff.py) code.

The part of the code is:

```
def recenter_poses(poses):
poses_ = poses+0
bottom = np.reshape([0,0,0,1.], [1,4])
c2w = poses_avg(poses)
c2w = np.concatenate([c2w[:3,:4], bottom], -2)
bottom = np.tile(np.reshape(bottom, [1,1,4]), [poses.shape[0],1,1])
poses = np.concatenate([poses[:,:3,:4], bottom], -2)

poses = np.linalg.inv(c2w) @ poses
poses_[:,:3,:4] = poses[:,:3,:4]
poses = poses_
return poses
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "run_nerf.py", line 12, in <module>
     from load_llff import load_llff_data   
File "/home/DNN/Softwares/nerf-master/load_llff.py", line 176
     poses = np.linalg.inv(c2w) @ poses
                                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax``
```

I really appreciate any help! I am new at this. Thanks :)

Comment: The `@` matrix multiplication operator [was introduced in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python). Looks like you're running this code on an earlier Python version

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` is not supported before Python 3.5. If you have an older version, perhaps you can run this way using [`numpy.dot`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html):

```
poses = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(c2w), poses)
```

[PEP465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)

Comment: @TanyaStevens Welcome to Stack Overflow! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers