# the usage of @ operator in an implementation of extending nn.Module

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I saw the following code segment for extending `nn.Mudule`. What I do not understand is the `input_ @ self.weight` in `forward` function. I can understand that it is try to use the weight information of `input_`. But `@` is always used as decorator, why it can be used this way?

```
class Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_size, out_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(in_size, out_size))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(out_size))

    def forward(self, input_):
        return self.bias + input_ @ self.weight

linear = Linear(5, 2)
assert isinstance(linear, nn.Module)
assert not isinstance(linear, PyroModule)

example_input = torch.randn(100, 5)
example_output = linear(example_input)
assert example_output.shape == (100, 2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the '@=' symbol for in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python)

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/

Comment: Clearly, `@` is *not* always used as a decorator.

Answer (score 3):

The [`@`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385633/what-is-the-symbol-for-in-python) is a shorthand for the [`__matmul__`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html) function: the matrix multiplication operator.

Comment: I know this `@` operator is used in numpy also. Is it safer to write `torch.matmul(a,b)` so we don't confuse numpy and PyTorch operators?

Comment: @prosti If you know you are working with `torch.Tensor` and not `numpy.array`, then it makes sense to use `@` as a shorthand and it wouldn't introduce any confusion. Of course, you can still write `torch.matmul` or alternatively use [`torch.Tensor.matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.matmul.html?highlight=matmul#torch.Tensor.matmul) but it's a little more verbose IMO. It just comes down to personal preferences or team conventions.

Comment: Great answer, so the `@` operator is just a function and there is one defined for numpy arrays and one for PyTorch tensors.

Comment: Is `torch.mm()` is almost the same as `torch.matmul()` or they are the same? I hope my question is not to broad.......

Comment: Indeed, in practice, the interpreter will look at the class of both operands and search for the appropriate operation. Which means `tensor_a @ tensor_b` will translate to `tensor_a.matmul(tensor_b)`, and will end up calling `torch.matmul(tensor_a, tensor_b)`... I believe `torch.mm` only performs matrix multiplications, while `torch.matmul` is a more general operator (more capable than `torch.mm`) and can perform broadcasting on the operands (see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html#torch.matmul)).